# JQueryMobile 'not' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to append the MainDisplay Variable to id div element called searchoutputtable

```
<div id="searchoutputtable">
</div>
```

Here is the code I use to do this:

```
    $.getJSON(AddressAccess+Build,
    function(data)
    {
     //Do a lot of manipulations to MainDisplay Variable
$('#searchoutputtable').append(MainDisplay);
    window.location.href = "#resultssearch";
    });
```

Now everytime this happends I get the following error in my javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'not' of undefined
```

Now when I console.log the element searchoutputtable I get what I am looking to do it appends everything perfectly the only problem is when we exit the getJson function that I get that error and my element isn't displayed at all.

Note I'm using jQueryMobile, yes I load the libraries correctly and I'm not using the .not() in jQuery at all so I'm not understanding what 'not' they are referring to in the error above

Comment: In which line exactly you get that error?

Comment: When I exit out of the getJson function

Comment: Provide the line that causes an error. I am not a wizard and I can't tell you what is wrong with code you didn't post here.

Comment: That's the problem the console doesn't give me a line where the code breaks down. The only thing that pops up is that error and that's on line jquery.mobile.js:2 of the jquery mobile script. What I have noticed is that if I comment out the $('#searchoutputtable').append(MainDisplay); line it works perfectly  fine. So I dont know if the problem is perhaps in what I am appending? But if that were the case wouldn't I simply get an error on that line?

Comment: Okay, replace your minified jquery.mobile.js with [normal version](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js) and then tell in which line is the error occuring.

Comment: Okay I've done what you asked and I get the following jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js:10970. Sorry I'm still a bit of a newbie.

Comment: What is the final value of `MainDisplay`? Are you able to reproduce that problem on jsfiddle? Or maybe give url to live example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using the reflow table widget you have to definitely make sure that you use the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags when working with tables. Thus in the above example my MainDisplay variable had a standard table in it without the thead and tbody tags and hence the error.

Comment: Wow I wasted an hour of my life until I found this. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

@GiddyUpHorsey is right. Actullay things are also written on tutorial site of jquery mobile.

Have a look at - http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_tables.asp

In reflow example it is written in hint area.